# OpenMP ensemble execution

Tags: openmp, fortran90

I am new to the OpenMP and at the moment with no access to my workstation where I can check the details. Had a quick question to set the basics right before moving on to the hands on part.

Suppose I have a serial program written in FORTRAN90 which evolves a map with iterations and gives the final value of the variable after the evolution, the code looks like:

```
 call random_number(xi) !! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
 do i=1,50000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
  xf=4.d0*xi*(1.d0-xi) !! EVOLUTION OF THE SYSTEM
  xi=xf
 enddo     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION
print*, xf
```

I want to run the same code as independent processes on a cluster for 100 different random initial conditions and see how the output changes with the initial conditions. A serial program for this purpose would look like:

```
do iter=1,100 !! THE INITIAL CONDITION LOOP
 call random_number(xi) !! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
 do i=1,50000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
  xf=4.d0*xi*(1.d0-xi) !! EVOLUTION OF THE SYSTEM
  xi=xf
 enddo     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION
print*, xf
```

Will the OpenMP implementation that I could think of work? The code I could come up with is as follows:

```
!$ OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(xi,xf,i)
!$ OMP DO
  do iter=1,100 !! THE INITIAL CONDITION LOOP
   call random_number(xi) !! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
    do i=1,50000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
     xf=4.d0*xi*(1.d0-xi) !! EVOLUTION OF THE SYSTEM
     xi=xf
    enddo     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION
  print*, xf
!$ OMP ENDDO
!$ OMP END PARALLEL
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Just put the call to `random_number` within OpenMP `ATOMIC` construct to prevent possible races. Otherwise the code looks OK (sans the missing `enddo` and the fact that there should not be a space between `!$` and `OMP` in the sentinel)

Comment: yes, missed that enddo. Thank you so much for your answer. I would like to generalize this for differential equations where there are subroutine calls with loops. Wanted to be sure, this implementation will not cause problems with loops doing weird stuff.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the input, the code worked like a breeze, and somehow, the call random_number routine worked fine. I read it online on certain forums that the internal routines are thread-safe. In anyway, atomic construct is something that I will always keep in mind for future.

Comment: My mistake - the construct should be `CRITICAL` and not `ATOMIC` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this line

```
   call random_number(xi) !! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE
```

might cause some problems.  Is the implementation of `random_number` on your system thread-safe ?  I haven't a clue, I know nothing about your compiler or operating system.  If it isn't thread-safe then your program might do a number of things when the OpenMP threads all start using the random number generator; those things include crashing or deadlocking.

If the implementation is thread-safe you will want to figure out how to ensure that the threads either do or don't all generate the same sequence of random numbers.  It's entirely sensible to write programs which use the same random numbers in each thread, or that use different sequences in different threads, but you ought to figure out that what you get is what you want.

And if the random number generator is thread safe and generates different sequences for each thread, do those sequences pass the sort of tests for randomness that a single-threaded random number generator might pass ?

It's quite tricky to generate properly independent sequences of pseudo-random numbers in parallel programs; certainly not something I can cover in the space of an SO answer.

While you figure all that out one workaround which might help would be to generate, in a sequential part of your code, all the random numbers you need (into an array perhaps) and let the different threads read different elements out of the array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think the generation of random numbers in the sequential part is in anyway a simpler option. I am sorry I forgot to mention I use intel fortran (ifort) compiler on ubuntu. Apart from the random number issue, the rest of the code according you to is fine enough for simulating the ensemble thing that I ought to do? Infact this is a simple iteration, at the later stage, I would like to generalize this for differential equations where there are subroutine calls with loops. Wanted to be sure, this implementation will not cause problems with loops doing weird stuff.

Comment: No, don't take my lack of comment on the rest of your code to mean that I think it is OK.  But do take @Hristo Iliev's approval as the reassurance you seek.

Comment: code worked like a breeze, and somehow, the call random_number routine worked fine. I read it online on certain forums that the internal routines are thread-safe. In anyway, atomic construct is something that I will always keep in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run the same code as independent processes on a cluster

Then you do not want OpenMP. OpenMP is about exploiting parallelism **inside a single address space**.

I suggest you look at MPI, if you want to operate on a cluster

Comment: True, dumb of me to mention cluster for OpenMP. Fixed that in the question. The definition was not very clear to me. Workstations with multiple cores is what I have. Though, if I have a workstation/node possessing 2 processors with 4 cores in each, with OpenMP, I can use all 8 of them together? I am still learning, just started yesterday.

Comment: Yes, if you have a dual socket 4cores/socket machine you can use them all in a single process with OpenMP, but, then again, you could use them all with a single threaded code using the shell to dispatch background jobs, which would meet your stated requirement *and* not require any new code...